# Accessing view config data from controller in Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a View which I instantiate like this. 'content' is some random data that I want to pass which I would use in the View and render the UI with this data.

```
   var nextView = Ext.create('MyApp.view.NextView',{
        content: content
   });
```

Now, on the view, I am able to initialize and access this data from within the initialize function of the View.

```
   iniitalize: function(){
       this.callParent();

       var content = this.config.content;
   }
```

Now, I have a method in my controller, where I want to get the value of this content. What is the best way to do that? I have been digging through the docs, and searching examples, but, haven't got anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In controller you would need to have `refs` section http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-refs

```
refs: {
   myView: 'nextView' // or whatever xtype of your view class is
}
```

And you will access your view (and all its methods and properties) by using auto-generated getter functions

```
this.getMyView();
```

Comment: But, I don't want to call any methods in the view. Rather, I just want to pick up the content value. This would still work in this case?

Comment: Absolutely. `this.getMyView().config.content` would give you what you want.